# Javascript OOP function printing as string

Tags: javascript, oop

Trying to get my head around javascript OOP, why is this causing the test method to print the entire function definition as if it was a string?

```
var Myclass = function Myclass(){
    this.connection = make_ajax();
    this.hasConnection = function(){return this.connection};

    this.test = function(){
        console.log(this.hasConnection); 
    }
}
var x = new Myclass();
x.test();
```

Result:

`log: function(){return this.connection}`

Comment: apologies I made a change

Comment: Because you're not calling it

Comment: Also, what's the code of `make_ajax`?

Comment: `var Myclass = function Myclass()` should either by `var Myclass = function()` or `function Myclass()`

Comment: There's also a missing `}` in the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because... you're not calling the function. You're logging the function itself, and since logging requires a string it calls the built-in `toString` method which returns the function as a string.

Try `console.log(this.hasConnection());`

Comment: Thanks for the insight, say I wanted hasConnection to remain a property with out having to call it, is there another way to store the result of the function inside the variable?

Comment: Isn't that just `this.connection`?

Comment: I suppose it could be yeah I just wanted an official bool, I like to make things more complicated for my self :P, i shall now remove the pointless addition but thanks for clearing up the function call thing :)

Answer (score 0):

When you

```
consloe.log(this.hasConnection);
```

you are logging the actual function, not the result of calling the function. Try changing this line to

```
consloe.log(this.hasConnection());
```